# Inbox, Reputation and Site Dropdown time inconsistency

Tags: bug, global-inbox, achievements-dialog, time

[image] [image]

Why is it only the Achievements drop down that has the time?

They both use exact dates, but only one has the UTC time.

Comment: Only diff is that the dup is a feature request and you report is as a bug. I think it is by design...so that is not a bug

Comment: @rene yeah, closed it :) It should be a feature request..